# date format in android

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I am stuck in one date format

i want my date should look like this, 18th Mar 2011
and it can be 1st, 2nd,3rd that means i want to resolve for all the aspects

Plz help me out for this ASAP

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: see it http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: thank for you reply but it work for php and javascript adn it want for java

Comment: @Jazz i think you want to change a particular date in 18th mar 2011 formatted way, right?

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to change date in a 18th, 2nd, 1st, 3rd dated way, if i am not wrong then you can use simpleDateFormat class to convert date in different formats.

Before using SimpleDateFormat, just refer the SDK documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

To have day number with nd, th, rd (i.e. 2nd, 4th, 3rd, etc.), you can use:

**`F  -     day of week in month    (Number)  -     2 (2nd Wed in July)`**
(given in the documentation).

For example using SimpleDateFormat:

```
String dateStr = "03/08/2010"; 

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```

Comment: hey paresh thanx for you reply and you are rite i want to convert date in 1st,2nd,3rd,4th... format. And the example which you have given is not for this format so can please tell me how we can use F in simpleDateFormat

Comment: @Jazz ya i have just provided a basic example to use SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: ya thanx for giving such example but i need to implement that 'F' into it, so how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

This is the term you are looking for: Quantity Strings (Plurals)

here is a link for it in the documentation:
[Plurals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Here is a link with examples:

[Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136288/how-to-do-an-app-with-truly-multilingual-strings)

And One more:
[Android Pluralization not working, need help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715014/android-pluralization-not-working-need-help)

Hope this helps. so you just need to reformat the string with the date by using the examples provided and thats it.